# Get value of Entity Object

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

[image]

I have picture like below.

I want to get value of project_id is 2,and number_request is 1.

But i can't get it.

I have use $data['items][0][project_id] and I print $data->items but i can't show it on screen.

Please help me.
Thank you so much.

Comment: try this `$data['items][0]->project_id`

Comment: Thank you. but it still not work. -_-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dumping objects doesn't necessarily give you an actual representation of the objects structure, but custom formatted debug information, defined via [**the magic `__debugInfo()` method**](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo).

Properties enclosed in brackets are special debug info, what is being shown there might have been gathered from anywhere but a property with the same name, see

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.3.4/src/ORM/ResultSet.php#L593-L598**

What you have there is basically a collection, so if you want the first entry of the collection, you can simply call `first()`, like

```
$entity = $data->first();
$projectId = $entity->project_id;
$numberRequest = $entity->numberRequest;
```

I would highly suggest that you study the docs a little more, as data access is really basic stuff.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Rows From A Table](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Accessing Entity Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessing-entity-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\ResultSet](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.ORM.ResultSet.html)**

Comment: Your support $entity = $memberInfo->first(); is correct.but need change $projectId = $entity['id'];
$numberRequest = $entity['number_member'];

Answer (score 0):

First you have to collect first object into an variable like

```
$val = $data->items; //its an object
$val1 = $val[0];
$projectId = $val1->project_id;
$NumberRequest = $val1->number_request;
```

Comment: It show error Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\ResultSet as array.

Comment: @VănTuấnPhạm can you please add your array output here so that I can run through script and give you the actual code, its a image I cannot write a array for this one.

Comment: Cake\ORM\ResultSet Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cake\ORM\Entity Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [number_member] => 1
                    [[new]] => 
                    [[accessible]] => Array([*] => 1)
                    [[dirty]] => Array()
                    [[original]] => Array()
                    [[virtual]] => Array()
                    [[errors]] => Array()
                    [[invalid]] => Array()
                    [[repository]] => Projects
                )
        )
)